Error when loading JPG image saved from TIFF: size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'
I have a TIFF image that I am saving as JPG using OpenCV, but when I try to load the saved JPG file, I get the following error:
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.10.0) /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:973: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'


Here’s the code I’m using to save the TIFF as JPG:
If I look at this image attribute with Ubuntu, the number of pixels is displayed, and the capacity is large, but when it is imported, the size is 0!!! :(
image = tifffile.imread("input_image.tiff")
image = image[y1:y2, x1:x2]
cv2.imwrite("output_image.jpg", image)


After saving the image as JPG, when I try to load it using OpenCV:
img = cv2.imread("output_image.jpg")
cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

I get the error mentioned above. The file seems to be saved, but I can't load it successfully.
The image is non-empty (it's not 0 bytes, over then 30Mbyte).
-> and this is too large to be jpg file,, same as png file
TIFF image is loaded correctly, and I can work with it before saving it as JPG.
The JPG file appears to be created, but it’s causing issues when loaded.
When I save the image as PNG, it works fine without any errors.
The problem is that the PNG file size is too large, so I need to save it as JPG to reduce the file size while maintaining an acceptable quality.
Has anyone experienced this before? How can I save a TIFF image as JPG correctly without running into this error?
